# How to enhance the build of a dataframe in loop?

Tags: python, pandas

Some people told me to change the way i am building my DF, using a dict and then a df.

How can i enhance this code in a pythonic way?

```
pos = 0
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Ticker', 'Headline', 'Link'])

elements = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_any_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, f'li[data-item="{d_N1_2}"] li')))
for elem in elements:
    data = []
    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView()', elem)
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of(elem))
    Ativo = elem.find_element_by_css_selector('span.primary-title').text
    Noticia = elem.find_element_by_css_selector('span.secondary-title').text
    Url = elem.find_element_by_css_selector('a').get_attribute("href")
    data.append(Ativo)
    data.append(Noticia)
    data.append(Url)
    df.loc[pos] = data
    pos+=1
```

The relation between elements and columns is: 'Ativo' in column 'Ticker', 'Noticia' in column 'Headline, 'Url' in column 'Link'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a dictionary, I would say as such

```
# Create empty dictionary with the column names
data = {key: [] for key in ['Ticker', 'Headline', 'Link']}

elements = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_any_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, f'li[data-item="{d_N1_2}"] li')))
for elem in elements:
    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView()', elem)
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of(elem))
    Ativo = elem.find_element_by_css_selector('span.primary-title').text
    Noticia = elem.find_element_by_css_selector('span.secondary-title').text
    Url = elem.find_element_by_css_selector('a').get_attribute("href")
    # Append the corresponding columns
    data['Ticker'].append(Ativo)
    data['Headline'].append(Noticia)
    data['Link'].append(Url)

# Create dataframe based on the dictionary
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```